# how to ignore request parameters in spring security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I want to implement `AuthenticationFailureHandler` with the following configuration:

```
// Auth failure handler
@Bean
public AuthenticationFailureHandler appAuthenticationFailureHandler() {

    ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler = new ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler();
    Map<String, String> failureUrlMap = new HashMap<>();
    failureUrlMap.put(BadCredentialsException.class.getName(), "/login?error");
    failureUrlMap.put(AccountExpiredException.class.getName(), "/login?expired");
    failureUrlMap.put(LockedException.class.getName(), "/login?locked");
    failureUrlMap.put(DisabledException.class.getName(), "/login?disabled");
    failureHandler.setExceptionMappings(failureUrlMap);

    return failureHandler;

}
```

and in `class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` I have:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/register", "/confirm").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                // username password
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                // success and failure handlers
                .successHandler(appAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
                .failureHandler(appAuthenticationFailureHandler())
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler())
        ;
    }
```

with this, all mentioned above is not redirecting to relevant failure URL, but if I remove

```
.anyRequest()
.authenticated()
```

then it is being redirected to relevant failure URL, but that is not good practice now the question is how I can configure the `configure()` to ignore /login?request parameter and implement further logic accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, the issue is that urls like "/login?.*" are available only after authorization. According to [spring examples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-javaconfig/blob/master/samples/preauth/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/samples/config/SecurityConfig.java), you can exclude paths from authorized access with the following code in Config file:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
        .ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**");
}
```